# replacing a string with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a URL like this:

```
http://Example.com/mobile-ds-cams/mobile-gg-cams/ddd-webcams
```

Example:

```
$pattern = '/http://Example.com/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/i';               
$replacement="http://Example.com/$2/$3";
$appUrl= preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $appUrl);
```

What I want to achieve is this

```
http://Example.com/mobile-gg-cams/ddd-webcams
```

I am trying to keep 2 "sub-URLs" instead of 3. but it doesn't work..why?

Comment: Don't forget to escape the forward slashes after the `http:` like this: `http:\/\/` and after the `.com` and every `(\w+)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work correctly because your expression contains characters with special meaning in a regex that have not been properly quoted.

To be 100% certain, use [`preg_quote`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) like this:

```
$url = 'http://Example.com/'
$pattern = preg_quote($url.'{word}/{word}/{word}', '/');
$pattern = str_replace($pattern, '{word}', '(\w+)');
$pattern = "/$pattern/i";
$replacement = $url.'$2/$3';
$appUrl= preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $appUrl);
```

**Otherwise, it's simply too easy to get things wrong.** For example, *all* of the other answers currently posted here get it wrong because they do not properly escape the `.` in `Example.com`. You can test this yourself if you feed them a string like e.g. `http://Example!com`, where `!` can be any character you like.

Additionally, you are using strings such as `$2` inside a double-quoted string literal, which is not a good idea in PHP because IMHO it's easy to get carried away. Better make that singly quoted and be safe.

Comment: Would this not leave each `/` after `(\w+)` unquoted - meaning too many delimiters? or have I missed something?

Comment: @Adam: No, I 'm guilty as charged. Thanks for the catch and it's true that `preg_quote` can be cumbersome. But for literals which are not cast in stone (an even stronger attribute than simply being hardcoded) it's too easy to introduce bugs otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape your forward-slashes within the pattern, or use different pattern delimiters.

```
$pattern = '/http:\/\/Example\.com\/(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)/i';               

$pattern = '#http://Example\.com/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)#i';
```

Comment: Close, but no cigar because you forgot to escape the dot. There's no reason to do this by hand and risk introducing (or retaining) such bugs: just use `preg_quote`.

Comment: @Jon Agreed, yes. I've fixed the escape on the dot (although it would've still matched). Personally, I find `preg_quote` makes code a bit more unreadable, but I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the slashes like this:

```
$pattern = '/http:\/\/Example.com\/(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)/i';               
$replacement="http://Example.com/$2/$3";
$appUrl= preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $appUrl);
```